# C# 2D Generic List

Tags: c#, list, nested-lists

I'm working on a talents/skills tree system for my game made with Unity and I've got a class for my 45 talents buttons that looks like this:

```
public class SaveTalentClass {
    public int talId;
    public int talCurRank;
    public int talMaxRank;

    public SaveTalentClass(int id, int cRank, int mRank)
    {
        talId = id;
        talCurRank = cRank;
        talMaxRank = mRank;
    }
}
```

I created 10 "Talent Lists" so the player can save different talents and I stored these 10 Lists in another List for easier access. So I've created a 2D list like that:

```
public List<List<SaveTalentClass>> containerList = new List<List<SaveTalentClass>>();
```

And added the 10 "talent Lists" into it but now I'm stuck trying to access/write in this 2D List.

I've tried a test like:

```
containerList[0][0].Add (new SaveTalentClass(0,1,2));
```

but got an error: `SaveTalentClass' does not contain a definition for`Add' and no extension method `Add' of type`SaveTalentClass' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I'm pretty sure there's an easy fix for that but I couldn't figure out how to do it !

Thanks for helping me :)

Comment: Maybe you wanted to use `containerList[0].Add(new SaveTalentClass(0,1,2));` to add the `SaveTalentClass` instance to the first list in `containerList`?

Comment: `containerList[0]` returns a `List<SaveTalentClass>`. To **set** the first item inside the first List directly, you would have: `containerList[0][0] = new SaveTalentClass(0,1,2);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have the containerList, you can add an object of the type on it, in that case is a List of Lists. So, add a new list of `SaveTalentClass` and after you can access it by `0` index to add an object of `SaveTalentClass` object, for sample:

```
// add the first list in the containerList
containerList.Add(new List<SaveTalentClass>());

// add an item in the first list of containerList
containerList[0].Add(new SaveTalentClass(0,1,2));
```

Comment: Wow ! Thanks to all of you guys for those fast answers, it really clarified how 2D Generic Lists works !

Answer (score 4):

Giving two indexes, you're already inside the second list. Either, if you want to add a new element to one of the lists inside the outer list, use

```
containerList[0].Add (new SaveTalentClass(0,1,2));
```

Or if you want to modify an existing one:

```
containerList[0][0] = new SaveTalentClass(0,1,2);
```